# Geometric interpretation of quantum Yang-Mills field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

In most books\articles review geometric interpretation of ***classical*** Yang-Mills field in terms of principal bundle, connections...etc.

What are geometric interpretation of ***quantum*** Yang-Mills field?
What is geometric nature difference between ***classical*** and ***quantum*** Yang-Mills field? (If the difference exists.)

Comment: Why do you think the geometric interpretation of the "quantum" Yang-Mills field is different from the classical one? If you are in the path integral formulation of QFT, you don't need to talk about "operator-valued fields", and so there's no real distinction between "classical" and "quantum" fields. If you want to do with operator formalism, the field simply becomes "operator-valued", but you still think of it as a connection on a principal bundle.

Comment: Particle in classical (Yang-Mills) field and particle in quantum (Yang-Mills) field it's physically different problems. It appears it is geometrically identical problems?

Comment: I think you're looking for the body of literature on [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization). In fact even the first section of the nlab article linked addresses this question directly.

Comment: There *are* no "particles" in quantum theories, just certain states we interpret as particles, but they have nothing to do with geometry. You can't "put a particle in a quantum Yang-Mills field", that's just not how quantum field theory works (but that's not specific to Yang-Mills fields).

Comment: >> but they have nothing to do with geometry

Yes, understand. Thank you.
Let the question has to be opened.

Comment: @ACuriousMind There is nothing in any theory! all we do is interpret, it's called "physics."  Why don't you think there is any geometric relationship to particles? So far every part of physics has been geometry, even the algebra parts...